# Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

How to give regular expression following numbers -

(state code 2 chars)-(sub code two digits)-(sub code 1 or 2 chars)-(number max 4 digits)

```
AP-05-BS-9853
KL-35-AC-638
OD-03-C-3843
```

I have tried this way. But not working

```
^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{1,4}$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^\w{2}-\d{2}-\w{1,2}-\d{1,4}$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Answer (score 1):

use group so that it will recognize it properly.

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{1,2}-\d{3,4})
```

this is working 100%

**demo** : https://regex101.com/r/zZ3eT7/2